# keras prediction output's decimal point without scientifc notation?

Tags: keras

Through Keras, I have a question while studying at CNN.

How do I output the results from the predictive calculation of the model to the fixed decimal point?

The results of my current model are `array([[6.527474e-05, 5.269228e-05, 9.998820e-01]], dtype=float32)`

I want my model **output** -

> (9.998820e-01) -> 0.9998820

Comment: The question is really helpful

Answer (score 4):

Both are actually the same. 
(9.998820e-01) and 0.9998820

you can enable this option, to display the numbers without scientific notation while you print the numpy arrays.

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```